# Are There Any Papers/Studies/Etc on Teaching L2 Learners how to Parse Speech by Teaching Them Phonotactics?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, phonotactics

Are there any studies in which subjects are taught the phonotactics of their L2 in order to help parse words out in their target language's speech?  All of the studies I have read concerning the subject just say that people use phonotactics when parsing out speech. Never have I seen a study that tests whether or not people learn to understand a language's continuous speech faster when they are first taught the phonotactical rules of their target language first.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the linguistics site. If you're not aware there is a dedicated [languagelearning.se] site which this question might be better suited for.